# Why are inline constructors and destructors not a good idea in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, inline, destructor

I remember reading in one of the C++ books (quite some time ago) that it is not a good idea to have inline Constructors and Destructors especially for derived class. 
I understand that inlining would induce some bloating up of object code but are there any other design considerations that discourage inline constructors and destructors? Of course most compilers may reject the inline and proceed with creating a function body but if they were to inline what penalty might one have to pay?

Comment: Note: The book is Effective C++ Third edition, item 30

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The compiler is free to inline code that you have not declared inline, and is free not to inline code that you have declared inline. I have seen compilers do both of these things. Because of this the inline keyword does not mean what most people think it does. It's meaning is to allow an exception to the one definition rule, so you can put functions etc. in a header file and not get linker errors.

So the advice is rubbish, let the compiler decide what is best to inline and what is not. Put inline where you need it to prevent linker errors, that is all.

Comment: +1 The same goes for `register` and `volatile `; modern compilers take liberties with these suggestions.

Comment: @s1n actually no. There are constraints as to how a compiler must use a `volatile` variable, which means that such variable will remain `volatile`. `volatile` is not a suggestion in that regard.

Comment: A clear, concise and completely correct answer. I can't believe how many people still believe that `inline` in this day and age actually directs the compiler to place the method definition inline. It's a linkage modifier and nothing more.

Comment: The compiler is free to inline code, and will but only if the appropriate inline everything optimizations are specified. --inline-functions or /ob2 in GCC and VS respectively.

When you define a constructor in the header file, the inline keyword is implied. So all of those should be considered for inlining regardless of the optimization setting. However in VS my own tests seem to indicate that this implied inline is weaker than specifying the keyword explicitly. And even forceinline will fail to inline in many scenarios. forceinline > inline > implicit inline > auto inlining.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about constructors, but destructors are very often `virtual`.  In most cases, it doesn't make sense for the compiler to inline virtual functions, because it's not known until runtime which override is going to be called.

Comment: Your argument is about virtual functions, not about constructors and destructors. It is not convincing regardless. The actual function is unknown only if called via a pointer or a reference. When called on an actual object, it is known and can be inlined. Declaring a rarely-inlined function inline can still make perfect sense.

Comment: @n.m.: I'm not talking about *declaring* a function `inline` (and neither is the OP, AFAICS).  I'm talking about whether the compiler will choose to inline a function.  I'm not sure what point the OP's book is trying to make; this is an educated guess.  A destructor very often **is** a virtual function, and very often is invoked in a polymorphic context.  But not always.  I'm not sure which part of that is unconvincing!

Answer (score 5):

There's absolutely no reason whatsoever to avoid inline constructors and destructors. The book is wrong as wrong can be.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to Effective C++. The book makes clear that inline doesn't always mean shorter or faster code. It suggests that inlining a method is a form of optimisation that should be considered very carefully. In that sense the book is neither correct or wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the reason @oli mentions in his answer:

The book probably guides on not inlining constructors and destructors, because even seemingly trivial or empty functions might often contain lot of implicitly generated code by the compiler and the actual function definition might end up being quite large, This might result in code bloat.

Having said so, It is prudent to let the compiler actually decide whether to inline or not inline a function call (even constructors and destructors), most of modern day compilers will appropriately optimize functions through in-lining.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is not about what C++ does with the code, because, as said, it's just a hint.

If you start looking at software engineering consideration things change. All inline function changes will force recompilations of all dependent files.

It get worse when you maintain a library and want to send out a bug fix version, remaining ABI compatible. Inline functions can simply not be replaced by another version because the calling code may not be recompiled. So where your non-inline function can be replaced at will, you have to move to a new version of your interface when inline functions ned to be changed.

Combine this with the fact that constructors can seldom be actually inlined by the compiler, then you I can imagine why a book would give the advice mentioned.