# inline constructor and destructor in cpp file

Tags: c++

As weird as the question sounds, I meant when a class is defined solely in cpp file because it is more of less a helper class for the implementation of another class and doesn't deserve to be in its private section. I understand that inlining constructor and destructors is a bad practice, but what about this situation, demonstrated as follows? Thank you very much

EDIT: I should have reworded it. In some cases inlining constructor and destructors causes bloated code unexpectedly(as discussed in Effective C++ Item 30, "Understand the ins and outs of inlining"). However I would like to know if such inlining demonstrated resulted in that as well

```
    // my_class.cpp
    #include <my_class.h>

    namespace {
        class Helper
        {
            public: 
                Helper() {...} // should I inline the constructor here?
                ~Helper() {...} // should I inline the destructor here? 
        };

        /* alternative implementation looks like
        Helper::Helper()
        {...}

        Helper::~Helper()
        {...}
        */
    } // end of anonymous namespace

    // implementation of my_class
```

Comment: *"I understand that inlining constructor and destructors is a bad practice"* Who says that, and why?

Comment: I should have reworded it. In some cases inlining constructor and destructors have bloated code unexpectedly. I would like to know if such inlining demonstrated resulted in that as well.

Comment: Found this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138234/why-are-inline-constructors-and-destructors-not-a-good-idea-in-c

Comment: And the top answer there states that defining constructors etc. inline is no problem, doesn't it? I mean, think of it that way: You are scared of *"bloated code"*, but when was the last time someone rejected your program because inlining some constructors made the binaries too big? Bottom of the line: Just let the compiler handle inlining until you can proof there is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a moot point.  Another discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138234/why-are-inline-constructors-and-destructors-not-a-good-idea-in-c) discusses this to a good degree.  The basic take away is that the compiler may ignore your "inline" or it may choose to "inline" the function/constructor/whatever without your input.  The inline command is simply a suggestion that the compiler is free to ignore.

TL;DR Go for it; it probably isn't going to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine either way. If ever a helper function becomes a performance bottleneck because it is not inlined, you might consider making it an inline function.

Many times I find that a single instance of the `Helper` class is adequate for use by the main class. Hence, whether the constructor and destructor are inlined or not does not make any difference at all.

```
namespace {
    class Helper
    {
        public: 
            Helper() {...}
            ~Helper() {...}
    };

    // The sole instance of the Helper class.
    static Helper helper;
}

void main_class::foo()
{
   helper.foo();
}
```